# Apache log - file does not exist

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, ajax, jquery

I have quite a few of these in Apache logs piling up every day:

```
[Mon Jun 09 20:42:58 2014] [error] [client 180.153.214.181] File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/ajax.googleapis.com, referer: http://www.mysite.com//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
```

I have over 200k visitors per day but a few of them like a dozen or so are generating the above error. I can't figure out what may be causing it. Checked the html code and it's all good so I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like wherever you're referencing to `ajax.googleapis.com` and/or `jquery.min.js` you're missing `http://` part.

look for `jquery.min.js` inside of your code `grep -r 'jquery.min.js' .` and add `http://` in there and i think error will go away.

Comment: I see this often with botched WordPress themes.

Comment: Thanks alexus, that small detail seems to have fixed it! Awesome!